# Gdi Guidance required

Tags: c#, gdi

I am currently working in C# with wpf, I don't know about graphics, I want to learn about GDI and graphics from scratch, Can anyone help me by providing some basic knowledge or material?

Can anyone tell me to write very first program using Gdi?

Comment: Hi,
One of the ideas behind WPF is that you don't need to digg into GDI/GDI+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn about WPF I really suggest "Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed" 
[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Presentation-Foundation-Unleashed-WPF/dp/0672328917](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917)

Also check out this video from the PDC - Mastering WPF Graphics and beyond:
http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/CL31

And if you still want to check out GDI you should read this book
[http://www.amazon.com/NET-Game-Programming-DirectX-9-0/dp/1590590511/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259061198&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590511)

It starts out with GDI+ basics and then moves on to DirectX.
Even though it's written for VB.NET you'll get a great deal out of it as a c# developer as well. It helped me back in the days and writing the games in the book is just downright fun :p

(Hint: There is a huge performance issue with the first example in the book, try to solve it, it'll help you understand things even better).

Comment: thanks, i know well about wpf, in fact i am working with wpf from last one year, but now my job requires me to have good knowledge of Gdi and Gdi+ also.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx), usually they have the best resource on the web. Also some tutorial website like [code-project.com](http://code-project.com) might help.